# error to save history chess into db sqlite django

Tags: python, node.js, django

I use django 2.1 and combine its with nodejs.
the game is ok but when game end, I want to save history into db of django. But it's not run. I'm not sure where is issue
static\main.js

```
winner = checkLogout !==  username ? username : checkLogout;
history= game.history();
socket.emit('endgame', {'gameId':gameId,'player1':player1, 'player2':player2, 'winner': winner, 'history': history.toString(), note : checkLogout });
```

nodejs\index.js

```
var http = require('http').createServer().listen(4000);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var host = 'localhost';
var port = '8000';
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('endgame', function(msg){
        var url = 'http://' + host +':' + port + '/save_game/';
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                if(xhttp.responseText === "error")
                    console.log("error saving game");
                else if(xhttp.responseText === "success")
                    console.log("the message was posted successfully");
            }
        };
        xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    });
});
```

game\views.py

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from game.models import Game
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
@csrf_exempt
def save_game(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg_obj = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        try:
            msg = Game.objects.create(gameId=msg_obj['gameId'], player1=msg_obj['player1'], player2=msg_obj['player2'], winner = msg_obj['winner'], history = msg_obj['history'])
            msg.save()
        except:
            print("error saving game")
            return HttpResponse("error")
        return HttpResponse("success")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

update code static\main.js

```
socket.on('joingame', function (msg) {
        gameId = msg.game.gameId;
        player1 = username;
        player2 = oppDict;});
```

Comment: Your `except` block is throwing away the error message, which probably contains useful information.  Try this instead: `except Exception as ex:`, and then `print("error saving game: %s" % ex)`

Comment: @JohnGordon, that notice: `[21/Nov/2018 23:40:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1127
[21/Nov/2018 23:41:07] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 446
[21/Nov/2018 23:41:10] "POST /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[21/Nov/2018 23:41:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1127
error saving game: 'gameId'
[21/Nov/2018 23:41:15] "POST /save_game/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7` but nodejs notice success `the message was posted successfully`

Comment: That error message seems to say that `msg_obj` does not contain a `gameId`.  Try printing `msg_obj` before the `Game.object.create()` call.

Comment: @JohnGordon, gameId not here `{'player1': 'han', 'player2': 'cat', 'winner': 'han', 'history': '[object History]', 'note': 'cat'}
error saving game: 'gameId'` and history not to convert to string

Comment: Okay then, the error is obvious -- your caller is not supplying a `gameId` argument.  How you handle that error is up to you.

Comment: I see my error because gameId is not same score. How to change value gameId from ‘Socket.on(joingame)’ go to gobal?